# Django get User Group in template

Tags: python, django

I want to get user group in my template but user group cannot show,

**views.py**

```
def Admin_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdminSetup(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            user.groups.add(Group.objects.all)
            post.save()
            return redirect('admin_add.html', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = AdminSetup()
    return render(request,'admin_add.html', {'form': form}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class AdminSetup(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Person, Operator, Owner, Contraktor, user.groups 
        fields  = ['username','password','email', 'group.name']
```

**admin_add.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User Group</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            {% for group in user.groups.all %}
                <option name="{{ group.name }}" value="{{ group.name }}">{{ group.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are u sure this user is in a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to add a group to a user.
If that's right, you can try below code

## views.py

```
def Admin_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdminSetup(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            group_name = request.POST.get('group_name')
            g = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
            g.user_set.add(user)
            post.save()
            return redirect('admin_add.html', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = AdminSetup()
        groups = Group.objects.all()
    return render(request,'admin_add.html', {'form': form, 'groups': groups}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

## admin_add.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User Group</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            {% for group in groups %}
                <option name="group_name" value="{{ group.name }}">{{ group.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but still not working. in my conditition, i already input 3 groups in admin. and i want to show that in my template, but its not show anything. how?

Comment: @Gergő Leonidas  I have never define  meta like  `class Meta:
        model  = Person, Operator, Owner, Contraktor, user.groups` , I think `user.groups` here is the problem. So I directly get `groups` through Group model, then pass `groups` to template. I think this is the most proper way to list groups.